# Retain Subview contents from one View Controller to another

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cordova

I'm using the Cordova cleaver to insert some subview into parts of my native app. I'm having difficulty retaining the contents of these subviews between the pages of my app. For example if I go from ViewController1 to ViewController2 and then back again the contents of the subview on the first view controller has reset as if it had just been loaded for the first time. I'd like a way to preserve these subviews across the app so they don't reset as a user moves around.

Here's what I'm doing right now:

Retaining the subview as a property in ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,retain) CDVViewController* viewController;

@end
```

And then loading it here like so in ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize viewController;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
viewController = [CDVViewController new];

viewController.useSplashScreen = NO;


viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 450);
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Any help or pointing in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So do you want to preserve the state of ViewController1 or ViewController2?

Comment: I want to able to preserve whichever ones I need to. ViewController1 for now if you can help with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few approaches you could take here.  One of them is to use a singleton pattern for your view controller, so that only one instance is ever created. With that pattern, the view controller will retain its state because it will never be re-created. An example of that pattern for objective c is [here](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/).

But that may not be the best approach. Another option is to store the parts of your view controller that you want to keep the same as static variables, so that if a new instance of the view controller is created, the portions of your view controller that you want to preserve will still be the same.  If you do that, you can restore the state of your view controller in a viewDidAppear method.

If you were to use the second approach, I would do it like this.  First, remove the @property declaration from your header file for the CDVViewController. Then, in your implementation file do something like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

static CDVViewController *__MY_STATIC_CDVViewController;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    if( ! __MY_STATIC_CDVViewController ) {
         __MY_STATIC_CDVViewController = [CDVViewController new];
         __MY_STATIC_CDVViewController.useSplashScreen = NO;
         __MY_STATIC_CDVViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 450);
    }

    [self.view addSubview: __MY_STATIC_CDVViewController.view];
}

@end
```

I would add that this recommendation isn't the best overall approach for your problem, but it should work for your needs.

Comment: How would I store a subview? Am I on the right track with the retained property?

Comment: the retained property would not have anything to do with keeping the state of your view controller. The 'retain' property manages how the variable is managed in terms of memory management.

Comment: Edited my answer to give an example of how you might achieve this.